# Oauth2 - Redirect url to iis on Server 2012 R2

Tags: redirect, iis, oauth-2.0, callback, .net-core

I use Oauth2 to access a database in a cloud.
The code is developed in .net core 2.0.
The redirect urls are:

```
"AuthRedirectUri": "http://localhost:44378/auth/callback",    "PostRedirectUri": "http://localhost:44378/myapp/Index",
```

I get connected to the database when the app runs on the visual studio (iis express).  However, when the app is published on the local server (Windows Server 2012.R2) I receive an "invalid request" message from the third party web app. The published app is on `http://localserver:80/`. The solutions I have found in the web are redirecting to the localhost which doesn't work in my case.
  Which hostname/port should be used to receive the callback code on the server? Shall I change anything in the iis or the server?

Answer (score 0):

> The solutions I have found in the web are redirecting to the localhost which doesn't work in my case.
>   Which hostname/port should be used to receive the callback code on the server? Shall I change anything in the iis or the server?

As far as I know, the redirect url should be your application's domain or IP address which could be access by someone outside your server.

Normally, we will use your server's public IP address and add your IIS application's port as the url(If you have the domain, you you should bind this url with domain address).

I suggest you could find this url and access from internet to make sure you could access the web application.

Then you could use this IP address and port plus sepcial fomat as the redirect url.

Comment: Thank you @Brando Zhang. Having a public IP address is restricted for this project.

Comment: Could you please tell me details information about your third party server? Identity server? Google auth? Or something else?